# Ansible count number of lines in remote file

Tags: ansible

I would like to count the number of lines in a file with playbook, but the playbook should run remotely. It should be the equivalent of the linux command:

```sh
cat /etc/passwd |wc -l
```

Now I use this as workaround:

```yaml
- name: Count number of users
  shell: 'cat /etc/passwd |wc -l'
  register: usercount

- name: Write the user count
  debug:
    msg: "{{ usercount.stdout }}"
```

but it will be nice if it should work with an Ansible builtin command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookup of files execute on the controller, so, I would say that your best bet would be to [`slurp`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/slurp_module.html) the files then count the lines.

So, with the string representation of the files, you can use the [`splitlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) function of Python to end up with a list you can then feed to a simple `length` filter.

Here would be an example playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: node1
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - slurp:
        src: /etc/passwd
      register: passwd
    
    - debug:
        var: (passwd.content | b64decode).splitlines() | length
```

This would yield the recap:

```
PLAY [node1] ******************************************************************************************************

TASK [slurp] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [node1]

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [node1] => 
  (passwd.content | b64decode).splitlines() | length: '27'

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
node1                      : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```